# I tried to make Loading Data screen but the data doesn't load correctly even when it's already saved the data

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I was trying to make a Loading Data screen so it will fit perfectly and when the screen is fully loaded, fire a RemoteEvent that will load the data

I was expecting that this will work but instead of working, my data doesn't loaded correctly even when it's already saved on the previous game.

There are no error messages, as the codes are stable

I didn't tried any of the fixes, because I thought my code is fine enough.

Here's my code:

```
local function addData(player)
    local Profile = Instance.new("Folder")
    Profile.Name = "ProfileData"
    Profile.Parent = player
    
    local Books = Instance.new("Folder")
    Books.Name = "BooksData"
    Books.Parent = player
    
    local Interactions = Instance.new("Folder")
    Interactions.Name = "InteractionsActivity"
    Interactions.Parent = player
    
    local Settings = Instance.new("Folder")
    Settings.Name = "SettingsData"
    Settings.Parent = player
    
    local Coins = Instance.new("IntValue")
    Coins.Name = "Coins"
    Coins.Parent = Profile
    Coins.Value = 0
    
    local Diamonds = Instance.new("IntValue")
    Diamonds.Name = "Diamonds"
    Diamonds.Parent = Profile
    Diamonds.Value = 0
    
    local XP = Instance.new("IntValue")
    XP.Name = "XP"
    XP.Parent = Profile
    XP.Value = 0
    
    local Level = Instance.new("IntValue")
    Level.Name = "Level"
    Level.Parent = Profile
    Level.Value = 0
    
    local IsSettingsOpen = Instance.new("IntValue")
    IsSettingsOpen.Name = "IsSettingsOpen"
    IsSettingsOpen.Parent = Interactions
    
    local CurrentScreenOrientation = Instance.new("IntValue")
    CurrentScreenOrientation.Name = "CurrentScreenOrientation"
    CurrentScreenOrientation.Parent = Settings
end

local function loadData(player)
    local PlayerId = "Player_" ..player.UserId
    local SaveData = GameDataStore:GetAsync(PlayerId)

    if SaveData then
        player.ProfileData.Coins.Value = SaveData['Coins']
        player.ProfileData.Diamonds.Value = SaveData['Diamonds']
        player.ProfileData.XP.Value = SaveData['XP']
        player.ProfileData.Level.Value = SaveData['Level']
        player.InteractionsActivity.IsSettingsOpen.Value = SaveData['IsSettingsOpen']
        player.SettingsData.CurrentScreenOrientation.Value = SaveData['CurrentScreenOrientation']
        print("[GameData] Data loaded!")
    else
        player.ProfileData.Coins.Value = 0
        player.ProfileData.Diamonds.Value = 0
        player.ProfileData.XP.Value = 0
        player.ProfileData.Level.Value = 0
        player.InteractionsActivity.IsSettingsOpen.Value = 0
        player.SettingsData.CurrentScreenOrientation.Value = 1
    end
    
    ReplicatedStorage.DataLoaded:FireClient(player)
    print("[GameData] Firing DataLoaded RemoteEvent to Single Client")
end

local function saveData(player)
    local SaveData = {
        Coins = player.ProfileData.Coins.Value,
        Diamonds = player.ProfileData.Diamonds.Value,
        XP = player.ProfileData.XP.Value,
        Level = player.ProfileData.Level.Value,
        IsSettingsOpen = player.InteractionsActivity.IsSettingsOpen.Value,
        CurrentScreenOrientation = player.SettingsData.CurrentScreenOrientation.Value
    }
    
    local PlayerId = "Player_" ..player.UserId
    local success, err = pcall(function()
        GameDataStore:SetAsync(PlayerId, SaveData)
    end)
    
    if success then
        print("[GameData] Data has been sucessfully saved!")
    else
        warn("[Warning - GameData] Failed to save data! Check your internet connection and try again!")
    end
end

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(addData)
ReplicatedStorage.LoadData.OnServerEvent:Connect(loadData)
Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(saveData)
```

Answer (score 0):

And again, as my previous asked question one, I found out why this happens

In Roblox Studio, DataStore always fails and sometimes just work, but in Roblox,  it's working like as expected.